# .NET add directory for dependencies at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dependencies

From my main C# application i instantiate another application via reflection.

```
assembly.CreateInstance( ... )
```

however this other assembly relies on DLLs which are in another directory than the executing assembly. how can i add this directory to the lookup path?

Comment: Pretty vague and pretty dangerous.  Best to use an AppDomain to do this to provide some level of isolation, AppDomainSetup lets you set the path.

Comment: yeah, i was already trying to use AppDomain for this, but it is always giving FileLoadExcpetions when creating an instance in the new domain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we implement this need in NDepend.PowerTools. These are a set of tools based on [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_introduction.html). The DLL **NDepend.API.dll** is in the directory `.\Lib` while the **NDepend.PowerTools.exe** assembly is inn the directory `.\`.

The **NDepend.PowerTools.exe** Main() method looks like:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {    
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolverHelper.AssemblyResolveHandler;
   MainSub();
}

// MainSub() is here to avoids that the Main() method uses something
// from NDepend.API without having registered AssemblyResolveHandler
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void MainSub() {
   ...
```

And the `AssemblyResolverHelper` class is:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;


namespace NDepend.PowerTools {
   internal static class AssemblyResolverHelper {
      internal static Assembly AssemblyResolveHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
         var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
         Debug.Assert(assemblyName != null);
         var assemblyNameString = assemblyName.Name;
         Debug.Assert(assemblyNameString != null);

         // Special treatment for NDepend.API and NDepend.Core because they are defined in $NDependInstallDir$\Lib
         if (assemblyNameString != "NDepend.API" &&
             assemblyNameString != "NDepend.Core") {
            return null;
         }
         string binPath =
              System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
              System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
              "Lib" +
              System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

         const string extension = ".dll";

         var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(binPath + assemblyNameString + extension);
         return assembly;
      }
   }
}
```

This works within a single AppDomain. I wouldn't use an extra AppDomain here if not needed. AppDomain is a pretty costly facility (in terms of performance) + the thread that jumps the AppDomains boundaries, has to serialize/unserialize in/out data to feed your assembly code, and this can be a headache.

The only advantage of AppDomain is that it lets unload loaded assemblies. So if you expect load/unload assemblies on a regular basis within the life of your main AppDomain, using some extra temporary AppDomain is the way to go.